# Set up sidewaysfigure to have the bottom of the figure toward the spine

Tags: floats, double-sided, rotating

I am typesetting a book. There are a couple figures that are wider than they are tall, and appear too small if placed on a page in the usual fashion.  I have found that using the `sidewaysfigure` environment from the [`rotating`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package, I can put these figures in landscape orientation taking up entire pages.  This is satisfactory except for one issue: in the compiled pdf, the figures are oriented with the bottom away from the spine; I want the bottom toward the spine.  If I use the package option `figuresright` or `figuresleft`, I can make the figure orientation independent of the page number, but this is not what I want.  The `clockwise` and `counterclockwise` options do not appear to change anything (which makes sense, since the documentation states that these options are for one-sided documents, but I had hoped).

In using the `sidewaysfigure` environment from the `rotating` package in a two-sided document, how do I orient the figures with the bottom toward the spine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange that there seems to be no such package option ... so I took the definition of `\end@rotfloat` and partially swapped the code for left and right hand pages. (And `\let` `\endsidewaysfigure` and `\endsidewaystable` to the new definition of `\end@rotfloat`.)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{rotating}

\makeatletter
\def\end@rotfloat{%
   \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
   \stepcounter{r@tfl@t}%
   \rot@label{RF\ther@tfl@t}%
   \rot@pageref{RF\ther@tfl@t}{\R@@page}%
   \edef\@tempa{Adding sideways \@captype\space on page \R@@page\space}
   \rot@mess@toks\expandafter{\@tempa}
   \wd\rot@float@box\z@
   \ht\rot@float@box\z@
   \dp\rot@float@box\z@
   \vbox to \textheight{%
    \setkeys{Grot}{units=360}%
    \if@rot@twoside
    \else
      \let\R@@page\rot@LR
    \fi
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\R@@page}}{%
      \if@rot@twoside
        \rot@mess@toks\expandafter{\the\rot@mess@toks (right hand page)}%
      \fi
% BEGIN OF ORIGINAL LEFT HAND PAGE
      \@@line{%
        \hskip\rotFPbot
        \rotatebox{-90}{\box\rot@float@box}%
        \hskip\rotFPtop
      }%
      \vfill
% END OF ORIGINAL LEFT HAND PAGE
    }{%
      \if@rot@twoside
        \rot@mess@toks\expandafter{\the\rot@mess@toks (left hand page)}%
      \fi
% BEGIN OF ORIGINAL RIGHT HAND PAGE
      \vfill
      \@@line{%
        \hskip\rotFPtop
        \rotatebox{90}{\box\rot@float@box}%
        \hskip\rotFPbot
      }%
% END OF ORIGINAL RIGHT HAND PAGE
    }%
    \rot@message{\the\rot@mess@toks}
  }%
  \end@float
}
\let\endsidewaysfigure\end@rotfloat
\let\endsidewaystable\end@rotfloat
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\rule{15cm}{1cm}
\caption{First figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\rule{15cm}{1cm}
\caption{Second figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is not a package option because rotated tables should have the top towards the spine.

Comment: @egreg: Yet there are the package options `figuresleft` and `figuresright`.

Comment: What happens in "one-sided" documents has no bearing with typography and this explains the `counterclockwise` option. :) I suppose that `figuresleft` and `figuresright` are thought for documents that have many rotated figures or tables, in particular if they are on a spread. Anyway, nice answer!

Comment: @egreg Can you give a reference for the claim that the top should be towards the spine?  I tried googling this to find the convention, but the only really relevant thing I could find was this question.

Comment: One reference is my _A Few Notes on Book Design_ : try `texdoc memdesign` to view it. The relevant section is _4.2.2 Mixed portrait and landscape pages_. In double sided documents on verso (even) pages the top should be towards the fore edge and on recto (odd) ages the top should be towards the spine. The basic idea is that the reader should always have to turn the book in a consistent direction to read any landscape pages --- to the right is the commonly accepted direction.