# Rotating sidewaystable

Tags: floats, memoir, double-sided, rotating

I use `memoir` to typeset a book. I've got a couple of one-page, horizontal tables. To typeset them I use the following draft code:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{ }
\label{ }
\vspace{-0.5mm}
{\footnotesize

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccccccccccc}
\end{tabular*}
}
\vspace{1.87mm}
\\
\tabSource{source}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

I have to rotate those tables so that the end of the table is always near to the spine of the book. How to accomplish this?

Comment: By "end", are you referring to the bottom of the table, or either end (table is always rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Yes, by "end" I mean the bottom of the table.

Comment: If they are the only `sideways` environments you have, you can use package options mentioned in section 2.1 of the manual for `rotating`. `clockwise` rotates the table clockwise.

Comment: The problem is that I have the "twoside" option on in my document. In that case the default behavior is to rotate the tables according to the page number: on even pages tables are rotated clockwise and on odd pages counterclockwise. I want them to be rotated according to the page number but on even pages it should be rotated counterclockwise and on add clockwise.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23635/set-up-sidewaysfigure-to-have-the-bottom-toward-the-spine -- my answer also works for `memoir`.