# Landscape table and section/chapter title do not fit together on one page

Tags: tables, landscape, section-titles

For my appendix I need to make a table in landscape mode, since the three columns containg quite a lot information and it has to fit on one page. Rotation for the table works just fine with both `lscape` and `rotating` (with `sidewaystable`) packages.

However, I am not able to fit the section/chapter title to the same page as the rotated table. The chapter/section is always on the page before the table. Including the chapter/section within the landscape mode boundaries does not work, since the title/chapter should be in normal portrait mode and only the table in landscape.

I have looked up already [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119802/rotating-package-sidewaystable-pagenumbering-not-rotated-expected) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118073/problems-with-landscape-mode-and-title-on-the-same-page). The solution of the first one does not work and I can not get the `\hvfloat` suggestion of the second one to work.

So the page should look somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title Here}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{Caption here}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
\toprule
Column A  & Column B      & Column C                   \\ \midrule
1234  & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    &  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you really need to rotate the table? Probably you can get away with keeping the table in a portrait orientation while allowing linebreaks inside of the two wide columns? This however depends a lot on the actual contents of the table.

Comment: As I understand it, this is a feature of the `rotating` package: rotated floats (`sidewaystable` and `sidewaysfigure`) always occupy an entire page.

Comment: @leandriis
unfortunately yes, the table contains quite a lot information and would be confusing using portrait mode.

Comment: @chsk
Oh that would make sense, since section/chapter title never fits independent of table size.

Answer (score 1):

To provide an actual answer to your question and not just a comment, you can use `\rotatebox` from the `rotating` package to manually rotate the `tabular` (this will not affect the caption though):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section Title Here}
        \begin{table}[tp]
            \centering
            \rotatebox{90}{
                \begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
                \toprule
                    Column A & Column B & Column C \\
                \midrule
                    1234     &   Foo    &   Bar    \\
                \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
            }
            \caption{Caption here}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Two notes:

- the `\caption` is not rotated this way, and
- the `table` is subject to the usual rules for placing floats.

Both are on purpose. FWIW I've used `tp` as placement options here --- I tend to believe that this produces the best-looking documents.

That said, if your appendix primarily contains wide tables and little associated text, I think having each of these tables on a page of its own would actually be the best option.

Another note: a better alternative (IMO) to `sidewaystable` is to put a regular table on a rotated page using `pdflscape` and `afterpage`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section Title Here}
    \afterpage{%
        \clearpage%
        \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}[p]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
            \toprule
                Column A & Column B & Column C \\
            \midrule
                1234     &   Foo    &   Bar    \\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Caption here}
        \end{table}
        \end{landscape}
    }
\end{document}
```

The nice thing about this is that the page will appear as a landscape page in any decent PDF viewer (so those viewing your document on a computer screen won't have to hurt their necks), while printing as portrait page with content that just so happens to be sideways.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Unfortunately, the second suggestions does not solve the problem of separate pages for section/chapter title and the table. However, thanks for 'landscape' good to know that such a alternative exists.
I guess since you already outlined that the caption of your first solution is not rotated there is no solution to that? Because with this suggestion I at least the section/chapter title is on the same page as the table.

Comment: @user239213 I would be surprised if there was no solution to rotating the caption as well, but I don't know how to do that; I'm no wizard (yet). You could perhaps ask in the chat about this, or post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your time and advice, I appreciate the help!

Comment: @user239213 You're welcome --- happy to help!

Comment: @user239213 BTW, if this answer helped you, it'd be nice if you could accept it by clicking on the checkmark symbol.